# Is it possible to send http requests from one thread and listen for the response on another?

Tags: multithreading, http

To send 10 http requests at the same time, I can make 10 threads, and have each thread send a request and wait for the response.

Is it possible to instead use two threads; one that quickly sends 10 requests without waiting for the response, and another that listens for and handles the responses?  If not, why not, and is there any way of doing what I'm suggesting?

Comment: On what platform? It's certainly possible "in general".

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by platform (I'm very new to computer science) but I'm on a Mac and I'm currently using Ruby - does that answer your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You should be as specific as possible when asking questions.  I've added the ruby tag for you.  If you've written code to attempt something, include the code you've written and explain what is not working or what you don't understand.

Comment: Why is platform important?  I don't really want an answer specific to Ruby if there's another language that can do it.  I'll just learn another language.

Comment: Well different languages will have different ways of doing it, that's all. Your question is basically too broad at the moment, precisely because it doesn't specify a language/platform.

Comment: So fundamentally the computer can do it? What determines whether a language can or cannot do it? If Ruby can't do it, I would want to know why, and then inevitably the discussion would move towards something more fundamental than the programming language (no doubt involving things like ports/sockets). Is it not possible for someone to answer the question at that level (which is really the level at which I want to understand it anyway), and then I can check for myself whether the language has the required feature?

Comment: I'm removing the 'ruby' tag.  It must be possible to give a general answer.  If nobody answers, I'll just come back at some point and answer the question myself.